# Probability that a chain will enter state $5$ before it enters state $3$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given transition matrix $P$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0.5 & 0.5&  0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2&  0.8 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.4 & 0.6 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix}$, how can we compute the probability that the chain will enter state $5$ before it enters state $3$ $?$

$$g(1)=0.5g(2), g(2)=0.8+0.2g(4), g(4)=g(1),$$ then I get $g(1)= {4\over 9}$, is it correct$?$ Actually, I do not very understand this one-step analysis mean$?$ Any help  is Appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general recipe: the probability to hit a set $A$ before hitting a set $B$ starting at a point $x$ is a function $u(x)$ which satisfies the system of equations

$$(Lu)(x)=0, \quad x \not \in A \cup B \\
u(x)=1, \quad x \in A \\
u(x)=0, \quad x \in B$$

where $L=P-I$ and $P$ is the transition matrix (taken in the row-stochastic convention, which is the convention you are using). You can prove this using the total probability formula, by conditioning on the outcome of the first step. For instance, in your case, $A=\{ 5 \}$, $B=\{ 3 \}$, and the first equation is:

$$u(1)=u(2)/2+u(3)/2=u(2)/2+0=u(2)/2.$$

The $L$ here is usually called the *generator* of the chain. The solution $u$ is sometimes called the *committor* of the chain (with respect to $(A,B)$).

In discrete space this is just a system of $|S|$ linear equations in $|S|$ unknowns, where $S$ is the state space.

Comment: so in this case, do we only need three equations, u(1), u(2), u(4)? then u(1) is the solution.

Comment: You have five equations, two of which are trivial ($u(5)=1,u(3)=0$). I don't know whether you need $u(1)$, you didn't give enough information to draw that conclusion in the original question.

Comment: I forget the initial distribution, X$_0$=1

Comment: Then yes, the solution to your question is $u(1)$.

Comment: @Ian I am confused that why $u(x)=1$ when $x\in A$. How to prove this? Is it possible that it starts from a state in $A$ but never hit $B$?. Thank you!

Comment: @EdwardWang This version views the situation as "if you are already in A or B then the process immediately stops". The other convention, where you always take at least one step, can also be handled but the solution is slightly different.

Comment: @Ian Then if the Markov chain is irreducible and finite state, is it true that the probability of you never hit a specific state is 0?

Comment: @EdwardWang Sure.