# Markov chain, probability of hitting some state before another

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $P$
$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac12 &\frac12 \\ \frac13 & \frac12 & \frac16 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
describe a Markov chain with state space $\{1,2,3\}$. Assuming that $X_0 = 1$ almost surely, compute probability that chain returns to state $1$ before it hits state $3$.

**My question:** let's define $u(i)$ as probability of visiting state $1$ before state $3$, starting at $i$. So as I saw in other solutions (like [Probability of reaching a state before a different state](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466164/probability-of-reaching-a-state-before-a-different-state)), I need a following set of equations:

$$
u(1) = 1 \\
u(2) = p_{21}u(1) + p_{22}u(2) + p_{23}u(3) \\
u(3) = 0
$$

I need $u(1)$, but... it is already equal to $1$, so what is wrong with my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $u(i)$ is the probability to be located at $1$ before you are located at $3$. This is not *exactly* what you want because as you say $u(1)$ is just $1$ but clearly it is possible to go to $3$ before you *return* to $1$ even if you start at $1$.

To fix it up, notice that $u$ does what you want if what you feed into it is the state *after one step*. Thus you can condition on the outcome of the first step and use the total probability formula:

$$P(\tau_1 < \tau_3 \mid X_0=1)=\sum_j P(\tau_1 < \tau_3 \mid X_0=1,X_1=j) P(X_1=j \mid X_0=1)$$

where $\tau_i$ is the first time $t>0$ where $X_t=i$. By the Markov property, that first factor in the sum is just $u(j)$.

Comment: so it should be $u(1)\cdot 0 + u(2) \cdot \frac{1}{2} + u(3) \cdot \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @AdamBogdański Right.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup seems to be correct, but the probability you are looking for is not $u(1)$, since you don't start checking if $X$ is in state 1 or 3 until it leaves state $1$.

Rather than looking at $u(1)=1$, set up a $\tilde{u}(1)$ that depends on transition probabilities and the various $u(i)$s. It should look like your formula for $u(2)$. This will give you the correct probability.

Answer (score 1):

Conditioned on $\{X_0=1\}$, the chain can return to state $1$ before hitting state $3$ only if $X_1=2$, and $\mathbb P(X_1=2\mid X_0=1)=\frac12$. Conditioned on $\{X_1=2\}$, the chain returns to state $1$ before hitting state $3$ with probability $$\frac {P_{21}}{P_{21}+P_{23}}=\frac{\frac13}{\frac13+\frac16} = \frac23.$$
So the desired probability is $\frac12\cdot\frac23=\frac13$.