# Probability of entering a state before entering another state in Markov Chains

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am always confused with such questions asking probability of chain enters a state before entering another state, can someone explain the logic for solving these type of questions, there is one answer here on Stack Exchange but still confusing, I know that when probability asked, I need to use u, in this case starting in state X0=1, what is the probability that the chain enters state 5 before it enters state 3, so I need to find u15 I guess, but since it says before 3, I am confused. Can someone explain step by step ?
Let Xn be a Markov Chain on state space = (1 2 3 4 5 )
Transition matrix given below :
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0&0.2 &  0.8        \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.4&  0.6        \\
1 & 0 & 0 &  0 &   0    \\
0.5&0 & 0  &  0 &  0.5   \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: If you change states 3 and 5 into absorbing states with a new transition matrix $M$ then look at $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  M^n$ then you can answer your question

Comment: how did you decide on changing the states 3 and 5 into absorbing states? I try to understand the logic @Henry

Comment: You have a recurrent finite transition matrix so you will eventually almost certainly visit all states. The question is which of states 3 and 5 you visit first.  So making those absorbing (preventing you from moving on to the other) will help you find the probability of which you visit first

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450399/probability-that-a-chain-will-enter-state-5-before-it-enters-state-3